# Force the origin to start at a discrete value

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like to force the starting time of the below plot to start at "04:00". The x label values are defined as discrete values. I tried `scale_x_discrete(limits = c("04:00","03:00"))` command but this only limits my data to that specific time slot.

[image]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(time = c("04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", 
"04:50"), Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.00803858520900321, 
0.00964630225080386, 0.00803858520900321, 0.00803858520900321, 
0.00964630225080386, 0.0112540192926045)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
ggplot(melted_Status, aes(x=time, y=value, group =`Status`, color=`Status`)) + 
  geom_line(size=3) +
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(size=8), legend.position="right", 
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", 
                            "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00",
                            "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", 
                            "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"),
                   expand=c(0, 0)) +  
  scale_y_continuous(name="%")
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `scale_x_discrete(limits = ...)` argument to the same vector of values that you now give to the `breaks` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by `teunbrand` the `break=c(...)` was changed to `limits=c(...)`

```
gplot(melted_Status, aes(x=time, y=value, group =`Status`, color=`Status`)) + 
  geom_line(size=3) +
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(size=8), legend.position="right", 
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", 
                            "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00",
                            "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", 
                            "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"),
                   expand=c(0, 0)) +  
  scale_y_continuous(name="%")
```